How to conditionally apply view styles without losing view identity
TL;DR
How do I get this Label("something", systemImage: "star").labelStyle(state ? .iconOnly : .titleAndIcon) behaviour without losing the view identity of the label?
Full question
I want to conditionally apply a view style to a view. For example, based on a state I want to display labels with icons only or with icons and text like this:
struct DemoView: View {
    
    @Binding var state: Bool
    var names: [String]
    
    var body: some View {
        List(names) { name in
            Label(name, systemImage: "star")
                .labelStyle(state ? .iconOnly : .titleAndIcon) // erroneous line 
        }
    }
}

However, because .iconOnly and .titleAndIcon do not share a type, the example above does not work. What is the correct way to solve this issue? I am explicitly looking for a way to solve the issue that does not mess with the Label identity of the view. I have seen a lot of suggestions like the one below:
struct DemoView: View {
    
    @Binding var state: Bool
    var names: [String]
    
    var body: some View {
        List(names) { name in
            if state {
                Label(name, systemImage: "star")
                    .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
            } else {
                Label(name, systemImage: "star")
                    .labelStyle(.titleAndIcon)
            }
        }
    }
}

The problem with this solution is, that the view identity of the Label gets lost when the state changes. This causes issues with animations, for example. (The same is true for the very un-swifty .if(...) view modifier "solution" that is floating around various threads.)
So, how do I conditionally apply different styles (which differ in their type signature) to a view without losing the view's view identity?

You could move the styling to a custom LabelStyle and apply conditional styling there. Ideally, you would use ternary operators to apply the underlying styles conditionally.

I tried this, too. I face the same limitations in a custom view style as I do in the actual view.

You have to understand that the purpose of these view styles is to separate the "presentation" from the "model". A Label is practically just a tuple of a title and icon - how these are laid out are determined by the label style applied.
The LabelStyle protocol is just a single function makeBody taking a title and icon (bundled in a Configuration) and returns an arbitrary View indicating how they should be laid out.
All that is to say, different views styles must have different view identities, by design.
If you want to maintain identity, you must use a single style, and express the view identities in makeBody. For example, for iconOnly vs titleAndIcon,
struct MyCustomStyle: LabelStyle {
    let iconOnly: Bool
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
         HStack {
             configuration.icon
             if !iconOnly {
                 configuration.title
             }
         }
    }
}

.labelStyle(MyCustomStyle(iconOnly: state))

Of course, this will not look exactly the same as the built-in styles, and this is by design. There is no relationship between .iconOnly and .titleAndIcon as far as SwiftUI is concerned.
It is only our intuitions that screams "look they both have an icon so the icon should have the same identity". Their makeBody implementations could be vastly different from each other and the two styles may look very different in specific situations.
In other words, by not providing a style like the one I wrote above, Apple reserves the right to design these styles in ways that doesn't make sense to switch between "icon only" and "title and icon".
In short, if you want your own dynamic style, write your own style and don't use the system ones.

Thank you for this in depth explanation, it really helped me a lot understanding the behin-the-scenes!

As suggested in a comment, you can use a custom LabelStyle for this.
Also, if the state flag is not being updated in the view then it does not need to be a Binding, just use let instead.
struct MyLabelStyle: LabelStyle {
    let state: Bool
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        HStack {
            configuration.icon
            if state {
                configuration.title
            }
        }
        .foregroundStyle(state ? .yellow : .red)
        .fontWeight(state ? .bold : .regular)
    }
}

struct DemoView: View {
    let names: [String]
    let state: Bool

    var body: some View {
        List(Array(names.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { offset, name in
            Label(name, systemImage: "star")
                .labelStyle(MyLabelStyle(state: state))
        }
    }
}

Example use:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var state = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            DemoView(names: ["Fred", "Tom"], state: state)
            DemoView(names: ["Harry", "Mike"], state: !state)

            Button("Toggle") {
                withAnimation {
                    state.toggle()
                }
            }
            .buttonStyle(.bordered)
            .padding()
        }
        .frame(height: 350)
    }
}


